# Parental Gate issue in kids app how to solve for Unity3D?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am facing issue when I am publishing my kids app to app store. My app was rejected due parental gate issue. I am using unity3D for development of kids app.

How can I implement parental gate into my kids app?

Thanks

Comment: You should maybe be more specific and include some kind of error log, etc. Not sure this question is on topic for SO

Comment: There is no one way apparently. Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/parental-gates/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a published game on App Store, but this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129734/how-to-implement-a-parental-gate-for-ios-apps-in-the-kids-section) question may help. More info on this topic [here](https://community.clickteam.com/threads/88621-iOS-App-quot-Made-for-Kids-quot-rejected-because-inApp-not-behind-Parental-Gate). Hope it helps ;)